# How to reduce the number of data points displayed in react-chart-js2 (data decimation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am using react-chartjs-2 to render a line chart with price data over a given period of time (e.g. price for past week, past month, YTD, etc.). When displaying more than 60 or so days of price data the line starts to get cluttered. So, I want to reduce the number of data points that appear on the chart while still representing the whole range of data.

I came across the plugin chartjs-pluging-downsample, which seems like it should work:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-downsample

Also the react-chartjs-2 docs describe a way to extend the Chart but I haven't been able to figure out the plugin code

```
import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2';

componentWillMount() {
  Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterDraw: function (chart, easing) {
      // Plugin code.
    }
  });
}
```

```
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import 'chartjs-plugin-downsample';

<Line
  ref={(reference) => this.chartReference = reference }
  options={{
    responsive: true,
    downsample: {
    enabled: true,
    threshold: 50,
    auto: false, // don't re-downsample the data every move
    onInit: true, // but do resample it when we init the chart (this is default)

    preferOriginalData: true, // use our original data when downscaling so we can downscale less, if we need to.
    restoreOriginalData: false, // if auto is false and this is true, original data will be restored on pan/zoom - that isn't what we want.
    }
  }}
  data={this.makeChart}
/>
```

How can I use this plugin (or some other method) to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I think I've figured it out and it's hilariously simple, I printed the object imported from `chartjs-plugin-downsample` and it came out looking suspiciously like the thing you're meant to pass to the plugin service.

So the way to do this is:

```
import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import DownsamplePlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-downsample';

...(component declaration)...

componentWillMount() {
  Chart.plugins.register(DownsamplePlugin);
}

...(rest of your component)...
```

and then just play around with the options. Make sure to set your `min` and `max` options, I've had it do weird things otherwise.

Comment: I haven't quite gotten this to work for my specific use case but at least you're way of registering the plugin works so I think this is the accepted answer at the moment. Also for anyone reading I should have used `componentDidMount() {...}` because `componentWillMount() {...}` is deprecated.

Comment: In the end I gave up on trying to make the plugin work, it was still doing strange things with my axis, so I wrote my own data decimation script. Should've just done that from the start.

Comment: Haha, I understand and thank you for trying! If you care to share your own data decimation script I'd be interested to see what does work for you. Cheers

Comment: I had a slightly specific use-case, so the code is suited for that (I was plotting a 1-5 star score over time). It's neither pretty, nor (I suspect) efficient, but it does the job and it does it well enough.
I ended up adding a slider for choosing the max number of points to display also.
You may notice if you go through it that when it combines two points, it remembers the original data also, not just the sum or average. I did this because I have a tool-tip when hovering over a data point that shows what time-span that point represents, and how many of each star-rating was gotten there.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/B0EmzJc2

To summarise, I chose the "merge closes two until there are few enough" approach because it is good at preserving extremes while not being too complex.
In retrospect I should really be normalising my data first, but I've already spent too much time on the graph and it's not required to be 100% accurate, so I'll let it float.

Comment: Ok I lied, it wouldn't let me sleep so here's the normalised version: https://pastebin.com/MPCChEfn

Comment: Awesome, thanks for sharing! When I have more time I want to add data decimation to this project: https://git-masi.github.io/bitcoin-data-visualizer/#/price-index so I'll post up the code when I get to it.